# How to reinitialize injected component in controller with Guice?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, playframework-2.0, guice, playframework-2.4

I have a controller :

```
public class MyController extends Controller {

    private final AuthChecker authChecker;

    @Inject
    public MyController(AuthChecker authChecker) {
        this.authChecker = authChecker;
    }

    public Promise<Result> index() throws BusinessException {
        authChecker
            .tokenValue(request().username())
            .execute()
            .go();
        // bla bla bla
    }

}
```

And I have a problem with `AuthChecker` because it keeps an internal state that is not reinitialized between each request. The initialization of this class is done in its constructor, which is executed only once whereas it is not a `@Singleton`

According to [Play's documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaDependencyInjection#Component-lifecycle) :

> New instances are created every time a component is needed. If a
>   component is used more than once, then, by default, multiple instances
>   of the component will be created. If you only want a single instance
>   of a component then you need to mark it as a singleton.

I want for every request to tell Guice to create a new instance.
How can I solve this problem ?

Also, are controllers singletons ? Because they seem to be created only once in the whole application lifecycle.

Thanks.

Comment: Controllers are singletons indeed. Because of that only one instance of 'AuthChecker` is created per controller. In other words, all requests of a specific controller share the exact same `authChecker` instance. You can either adjust the [scope](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes) of `MyController` or write a stateless version of `AuthChecker`. IMO the second approach is preferrable.

Comment: Thanks. Yes the second one seems preferrable after reading your link. But are we sure `Controllers` are thread safe ? What happens if two request arrive at the same time ?

Comment: For a direct answer to your question, inject a `Provider<AuthChecker>` instead of plain `AuthChecker`.

Comment: @c4k: Well writing thread safe controllers is in your responsibility. Two requests will run in parallel and independent of each other in that case. If your controller is not thread safe, for instance when you modify an instance variable in an action, the application will become non deterministic. I can add an example somewhen this weekend if you like. Just let me know.

Comment: @Roman : yes I'd like an example please ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Provider, meaning guice creates a new instance (if not configured otherwise in your module) everytime you access it:

```
public class MyController extends Controller {

    private final Provider<AuthChecker> authChecker;

    @Inject
    public MyController(Provider<AuthChecker> authChecker) {
        this.authChecker = authChecker;
    }

    public Promise<Result> index() throws BusinessException {
        authChecker.get()
            .tokenValue(request().username())
            .execute()
            .go();
        // bla bla bla
    }

}
```